# Preserve text in Jquery Virtual Keyboard

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui, keyboard

I am using `Jquery Virtual Keyboard` from [here](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/). My Problem is that when i enter something in textbox and click somewhere else in page. The entered value gets disappeared. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/550/).
How can i preserve text in that textbox even someone click on other parts of webpage ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **`autoAccept : true`** in your option ?

http://jsfiddle.net/MK947/1864/